# create new variables in R

Tags: r

I have two variables `TEMPD`, and `ENERGY`

I want to create two new variables `TEMP2` and `TEMP3` by doing something like:

```
tempd2 = tempd^2;
tempd3 = tempd^3;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `d = transform(d, tempd2 = tempd^2, tempd3 = tempd^3)`, also `d = plyr::mutate(d, tempd2 = tempd^2, tempd3 = tempd * tempd^2)`

Comment: @baptiste : you're pure evil!

Comment: What you have works, or doesn't it for you @Clay?

Comment: i meant `d = plyr::mutate(d, tempd2 = tempd^2, tempd3 = tempd * tempd2)`, obviously, to illustrate that mutate can use variables you just defined.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What you have here will work, but in R you use `<-` instead of `=`.

```
temp <- 2
energy <- 16

temp2 <- temp^2
energy2 <- energy^2
```

Checking the outcomes:

```
> temp2
 [1] 4
> energy2
 [1] 256
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Lenwood!! I did not realized what I was doing wrong. it must be getting late because I forgot to but the data$temp^2.... And you can use = ?!

Comment: In almost all cases, `=` will work just as well as `<-`. Most R traditionalists will prefer `<-`, but in practice you would rarely be caught out using `=`. One example is using `system.time`: `system.time(x <- rnorm(1e5))` is not the same as `system.time(x = rnorm(1e5)` (and the latter will give an error).

Comment: Thanks seancarmdy its good to know for later on down the road.

Comment: -1, the `<-` is not the solution here. The code the OP presented works.